# I need a 301 redirect for .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I need a redirect from

1. `https://example.com/shop/vip-schmuck/18-karat-gold/18-karat-gold-nasenstecker-spirale-schmetterling-kristalle/`

to

2. `https://example.com/shop/vip-schmuck/18-karat-gold/280419/18-karat-gold-nasenstecker-spirale-schmetterling-kristalle/`

what means 1 is the old URL und 2 is the new one.

The only change is the "280419" in the new URL.

**UPDATE:**

I want to redirect all of my product URLs. ie. from `example.com/shop/placeholderhere/placeholderhere/placeholderhere/` to `example.com/shop/placeholderhere/placeholderhere/280419/placeholderhere/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the top of your root `.htaccess` file you can do something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^(shop/vip-schmuck/18-karat-gold)/(18-karat-gold-nasenstecker-spirale-schmetterling-kristalle/)$ /$1/280419/$2 [R=302,L]
```

The `$1` and `$2` backreferences in the *substitution* string (2nd argument) contain the values captured from the parenthesised subpatterns in the preceding `RewriteRule` *pattern*. This simply saves repetition (and potential error).

This is a 302 (temporary) redirect. Only change to a 301 (permanent) redirect - if that is the intention - once you have confirmed this works as intended.

Reference:

- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule

---

**UPDATE:**

> i want to redirect alll of my producs , what means old protect-`example.com/shop/placeholderhere/placeholderhere/placeholderhere/` to protect-`example.com/shop/placeholderhere/placeholderhere/280419/placeholderhere/`

To *inject* the code `280419` in every URL that follows that format you can do something like this instead:

```
RewriteRule ^(shop/[^/]+/[^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /$1/280419/$2/ [R=302,L]
```

Where `$1` contains the URL-path that matches the first subpattern `(shop/[^/]+/[^/]+)` and `$2` matches the last path segment (excluding an optional trailing slash) as denoted by `([^/]+)/?$`. The trailing slash is enforced on the target URL.

Comment: Well, first thank you for your response.
Second..i asked the question wrong. :-(
As far as i understand i need a redirect match, cause i want to redirect alll of my producs , what means

old
protect-piercing.de/shop/placeholderhere/placeholderhere/placeholderhere/
to
protect-piercing.de/shop/placeholderhere/placeholderhere/280419/placeholderhere/

Regards Chris

Comment: @ChristianHeidingsfelder You want to inject the same code `280419` into every URL? (`RewriteRule` is preferable to `RedirectMatch` here since you are probably already using mod_rewrite to route your URLs.)

Comment: yes, thats exactly what i want :-)

Comment: @ChristianHeidingsfelder I've updated my answer.

Comment: Okay, first ... sorry for the late response.
I added that line to my .htaccess 
It seems to work :-)

https://protect-piercing.de/shop/vip-schmuck/diamant/18-karat-gold-segmentring-clicker-diamanten/

Many thanks :-)

Regards chris